# PDF plot generation behaves differently in R vs Rscript

Tags: r, pdf, plot, cmd, rscript

I have code that generates and exports plots on separate pages of a pdf for each iteration of a loop.
This code works as intended when I run it in RGui or Rstudio in windows 7.  However, when I try to automate it with windows task manager or Rscript through the command prompt, I get a generic, default sized Rplot.pdf output, rather than the mtcars.pdf formatted with the dimensions that I assigned in function pdf().
Here, I use mtcars to replicate my issue.  This code works as intended and generates a 3 page pdf named mtcars, with 7 by 5 dimensions.

```
setwd("C:/")
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
gear.cat <- unique(mtcars$gear)
plots <- vector(length(gear.cat), mode='list')
for (i in 1:length(gear.cat)) {
sub<- subset(mtcars , gear==gear.cat[i])
p1 <- ggplot(sub, aes(mpg, wt))+geom_point() 
p2 <- ggplot(sub, aes(hp, cyl))+geom_point() 
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2),   size = "last" )) 
plots[[i]] <- recordPlot()
 }
graphics.off()

pdf("mtcars.pdf", onefile=TRUE, width=7 ,height=5 )
for (each.plot in plots) {
replayPlot(each.plot)
 }
graphics.off()
```

When I run same script from the cmd prompt:

```
 RScript C:\mtcars.example.R
```

I get a pdf with plots 7 x 7 plots on 3 pages named rplots.pdf, and a corrupt mtcars.pdf file.

When I export pdfs on separate pages, according to the following code, it works as intended in R and Rscript.

```
 setwd("C:/")
 library(ggplot2)
 library(grid)
 gear.cat <- unique(mtcars$gear)
 for (i in 1:length(gear.cat)) {
 sub<- subset(mtcars , gear==gear.cat[i])
 p1 <- ggplot(sub, aes(mpg, wt))+geom_point() 
 p2 <- ggplot(sub, aes(hp, cyl))+geom_point() 
 pdf(paste0("mtcarsb", gear.cat[i], ".pdf") , width=7 ,height=5 )
 grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2),   size = "last" )) 
 graphics.off()
 }
```

Any suggestions that allow me to generate multipage pdf plots in Rscript would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
   pdf("xyz.pdf")
   ## All plots commands in between the above and below statement in the script.
   dev.off()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not address my question as to why running an R script through the command prompt behaves differently than running in Rgui

Answer (score 0):

It seems that recordPlot and replayplot do not function properly in Rscript when using grid.  I instead used grid.grab, and now the following code provides consistent results when run in R or Rscript.

```
setwd("C:/")
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
gear.cat <- unique(mtcars$gear)
plots <- vector(length(gear.cat), mode='list')
pdf("mtcarsddd.pdf", onefile=TRUE, width=7 ,height=5 )
for (i in 1:length(gear.cat)) {
sub<- subset(mtcars , gear==gear.cat[i])
p1 <- ggplot(sub, aes(mpg, wt))+geom_point() 
p2 <- ggplot(sub, aes(hp, cyl))+geom_point() 
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2),   size = "last" ))
plots[[i]]<- grid.grab()
}
dev.off()
```